# Webpack2: jsx loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, jsx, webpack-2

I’m trying to migrate webpack 1 to 2, but have trouble with jsx:

```
ERROR in ./src/routes/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'SettingsPage' in '/Users/pavel/rails/spa_frontend/src/routes'
 @ ./src/routes/index.js 37:20-43
 @ ./src/index.jsx
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client ./src/index.jsx
```

My config for webpack2:

https://gist.github.com/pustovalov/0292a6094bea6cdec6f84c9fab5e4d2e

Comment: are you sure this error is coming from your config? what does your index.js look like?

Comment: https://github.com/pustovalov/spa_frontend/blob/specs/src/routes/index.js

Comment: i just cloned your project, built it, and ran it with no issues.

Comment: In branch master everything works well, I just fixed branch `specs`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This helped me:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss']
  },
```

Working webpack2 config:

https://gist.github.com/pustovalov/d82c2421acbb35fb4bf46a61c519ffe0

Comment: ohhhhhh didn't see this. mine did run fine when i cloned it, but when i setup webpack2, deleting the empty extension fixed and error for me as well.